# How to deploy an application on cluster using appscale?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, vagrant, virtualbox, appscale

I'm trying to run a GoogleAppEngine Application on my laptop using AppScale. I was following the instructions in this [link](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki/AppScale-on-VirtualBo) ,  and all goes just fine until the deployment part.

```
appscale deploy ~/path-to-your-app
```

I dont know what path i have to put. The directory that contain my application is on my desktop. so i did

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ appscale deploy /Users/Mac/Desktop/MyApp
/Users/Mac/Desktop/MyApp is not a tar.gz file, a zip file, or a directory. Please try uploading either a tar.gz file, a zip file, or a directory.
```

But the virtual machine doesn't have access to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must scp the application to the machine where the AppScale tools are located. Optionally there is a web interface to upload applications from the AppScale dashboard.